# Bootstrap DateTimePicker on change event not worked in jquery

Tags: jquery, html, asp.net-mvc-4

I used datetimepicker and i want to disable the previous date depends on other date value.But its change event is not worked.How to solve this problem.My code is below.This code inside a each function.

```
 $('#datepickerReturnedDate').datetimepicker({                          
                        weekStart: 1,
                        todayBtn: 1,
                        autoclose: 1,
                        format: 'MM/dd/yyyy hh:ii',
                        todayHighlight: 1,
                        startView: 2,
                        forceParse: 0,
                        showMeridian: 1,
                        minDate: new Date(value.IssuedDate.match(/\d+/)[0] * 1),
                    }).on('change', function (selected) {
                        var mindate = $(this).datepicker('option', 'minDate');
                        if (new Date($(this).val()) < mindate) {
                            NotificationPopUpDynamic("Return date cannot be less than issue date(" + mindate + ").", "failure");
                            $(this).datepicker("setDate", mindate);
                        }
                    })
```

Answer (score 0):

I have added the code on jsfiddle --> "jsfiddle.net/uLkazx8e".
 Please have a look on this. Your issue will be resolved. Thank you.

Comment: when i alert the mindate i got the selected date.Not the mindate value.How can i get  minDate: new Date(value.IssuedDate.match(/\d+/)[0] * 1), this property in onChange function.??

Comment: what is this ? could youi please tell --> value.IssuedDate.match(/\d+/)[0] * 1

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/uLkazx8e/
Please have a look on this. Your issue will be resolved. Thank you.